# Streaming reads and writes in Parsec

Tags: haskell, parsec

Given a `Parser` in `parsec` library, what is a good way to do streaming read (from input file) and write (appending parsed blob/line to an output file). Below is an example from `Text.Parsec.ByteString`:

```
main    = do{ result <- parseFromFile numbers "digits.txt"
             ; case result of
                 Left err  -> print err
                 Right xs  -> print (sum xs)
             }
```

The above example only reads from "digits.txt", and won't have the output until it has seen all the input. Let us assume that instead of collecting all the values and doing a reduction (`sum`) above, we want to write all `xs` out to "digitsOut.txt" in streaming way (read lines from digits.txt and write out to digitsOut.txt). Given `parseFromFile` signature, it doesn't seem we can stream lazily and pipe the output to an output file until we have seen all of the input. This is the type signature:

```
parseFromFile :: Parser a -> String -> IO (Either ParseError a)
```

So, it seems in order to determine whether there is an error or not, it will need the whole input. If I am not mistaken, the code can't write the output until it has seen all the input. Is there another way to do streaming input and output using `Parsec` (and not `AttoParsec` if it can be avoided - I will like to have access to error reporting of `Parsec`). The file that I am trying to parse is huge (50+GB). So, I need to hook up the parser code with streaming input and output. If there is a good example somewhere, pointers will be appreciated.

**Update**

Just found from `AttoParsec` [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.8.0.2/docs/Data-Attoparsec.html) that `Parsec` can't consume input incrementally. So, there is no way to do streaming in `Parsec`. I will now refactor the parser to `AttoParsec`.

Comment: 1) If all you're trying to read is numbers, and a large number of them, Parsec wouldn't be my first choice. Parsec is good for consuming human produced input of reasonable size. It's not a good fit (nor hugely beneficial) to consume huge amounts of completely uniform data 2) If you wanna stream, don't attempt to read the entire file at once using utility functions like parseFromFile. 3) Consider not putting all your 50 GB of data into a single file. Data of that magnitude is usually better kept in databases.

Comment: @Cubic, not wedded to `parseFromFile`. The question is about if there is any way of doing streaming within parsec - I just copied `parseFromFile` example to explain the problem. Also, regarding db thing - the parser is the loader to parse and generate data for the db :) Size is all relative, maybe :) I will split the file if it turns out parsec or attoparsec don't work well at that size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Parsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec) is generally focused on smaller amounts of complicated data. Think programming and markup languages, difficult binary formats and such. This has two effects:

1. It is optimised for error messages (needed with complicated data) over performance (not needed with small amounts of data)
2. It doesn't do streaming parsing (again, not needed with small amounts of data)

[Attoparsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec) takes the opposite approach: it's focused on large amounts of (comparatively) simple data. Think mining log files, reading measurement values, collecting a stream of data from the internet and such. This has two effects:

1. It is optimised for performance over error messages
2. It is built around streaming

The principle behind streaming parsing with Attoparsec is that you choose to parse something, and when it has consumed all your input, it will return a value which indicates it's expecting to be fed more input.

> Note well, however, a huge file might still take up huge amounts of memory even when you use Attoparsec to parse it. This is because Attoparsec (as opposed to Parsec) always backtracks when it fails to match a parser, so it can't throw away "already parsed" data because it might be needed later.
>
> The solution to this is, as hinted in the comments, to write a parser for only a single section of your data (something like a line of a log file) and then run that parser repeatedly from Haskell code for each line of your log file. This allows parsing to take constant space.

Comment: so perhaps hand-roll the input for attoparsec as documented here, to limit the memory (instead of keeping all the data - makes sense to throw away the successfully parsed data): http://newartisans.com/2012/08/parsing-with-haskell-and-attoparsec/ . Or may be it has been superseded by something else in attoparsec library like `takeWhile1` ?

Comment: @Sal No, I think you still have to do what they are writing about in that blog post. If you, for example, want to parse a log file, you can write a parser for a single line in the log file, and run that parser on just one line at a time. I might be able to write up an example tomorrow if you want.

Comment: yep, I got the gist. Basically, parse one chunk at a time. I will try out a solution myself. Since each unit of valid input is supposed to be small, say constant space, it should be fine, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

> Given parseFromFile signature, it doesn't seem we can stream lazily and pipe the output to an output file until we have seen all of the input. [...] So, it seems in order to determine whether there is an error or not, it will need the whole input. If I am not mistaken, the code can't write the output until it has seen all the input.

This is all equally true of Attoparsec as of Parsec. While Attoparsec gives you more control over the incremental consumption of input, it still gives parsers no way to express incremental production of output. The parser has to run to completion before it can report success, and the only way to get at the parser's output is via the data constructor that represents the fact that the parser succeeded.

Comment: Hmm, that will make sense. Doesn't the current attoparsec library has that support through `Partial` continuation? If that is not the case, and if you know of a toy example somewhere, pointers will be very much appreciated.

Comment: @Sal The `Partial` return value does not contain a partial parse, only the continuation function that you need to feed with more input. Only the `Done` return value contains actual output.